# what is the difference between TextField and text_general in solr

Tags: solr

I'm newbie to solr, through some tutorial I discovered that there is text_general type and I assume that it is used for text type (one or many word...) and then in the reference documentation, I found that there is also TextField that is also used for `Text, usually multiple words or tokens.`
so what is the difference between the two, and when to use one instead of the other

Comment: well, solr field analysis feature is best for you to find out answer for this question,create collection with fields assign datatype you want to explore then use analysis screen to explore behavior- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextField is a basic field type that is included in solr that you can used to index/analyze usually multiple words or tokens. Means you can use this for matching something part of sentence.

text_general isnt basic solr field type, it is simply extended type from text field which you define based on your **indexing** and **querying** requirement. So simply you create/define this field.

Sample field type for [text_general](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Type+Definitions+and+Properties)

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: so I guess that I can use both of them for phrases, but when I need advanced treatment ( for example removing stop word) it is better to use `text_general`

Comment: correct. You can add or remove according to what you need. this will help you in process https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers%2C+Tokenizers%2C+and+Filters